# как с помощью лямбда функций определить целое число

Tags: python

Напишите функцию is_num, используя синтаксис анонимных функций, которая принимает строковый аргумент и возвращает значение True, если переданный аргумент является числом (целым или вещественным) и False в противном случае.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/385597/14775762

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = lambda x: (x.replace('.', '', 1).replace('-', '', 1)).isnumeric()

print(a('-123.77'))
```

replace: проверяем есть ли отрицательные и дробные числа. И приводим их в целые и положительные.

```
b = lambda x: (x.replace('.', '', 1).replace('-', '', 1)).isnumeric() if x.find(".") > x.find("-") or x.find(".") == x.find("-")\
    or x.find(".") ==-1 and x.find("-") == 0  else False

print(b('123-'))
```

еще вариант

Comment: А разве топикастер это подразумевал? " если переданный аргумент является числом (целым или вещественным)". Дождемся его пусть покажет варианты строк. Впрочем спасибо за подсказку. Теперь Ваш тест пройдет)

Comment: `'.-1'` всё ещё работает.

Comment: По-моему тут без регекспов сложно будет. `123-456` тест пройдёт, минус надо спереди только отрезать.

Comment: Добавил еще вариант.

Comment: C `1e2` и `1e-2` не работает